# Get audio stream in React.js app from expressjs server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, streaming, spotify, audio-streaming

##### Greetings SO Community,

I had created backend in expressjs that have an endpoint that serve stream of requested audio/mp3 file within its bytes ranges.

> #### Say No To Progressive Download
>
> As I researched and came to know in progressive download there is a major drawback the file has to be downloaded from start to that point from where user want to listen even from the end. So, after this I got a solution from somewhere and specially from SO, then I decided to implement a backend to get an audiobook id and its section index from params and range from header and pipe the stream to the client side.

#### Found Similar Implementation to Spotify

After struggling with the frontend issues, I inspected Spotify web app; it is also getting content of a song in bytes ranges. I saw headers include Ranges, Content-Length etc just like me. But issue is how can I implement on client side. Need guidance to get an efficient approach. And strange thing is that I did not find any video or audio element tag in HTML content. But I am using audio tag and audio element Web API events to make a poor implementation.

## Why I am here?

> #### 1) Second Chunk Replacing The First Chunk
>
> I tried to get streams on client side (in my react app) and got the first chunk of file as stream then converted stream to blob url using `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` and gave it to the audio element (or any npm package like `react-player`). Then I request the second chunk (will be the chunk right after the first). Then again, I converted it to blob url and gave it to the audio element. Within this time frame my second chunk replacing with first chunk. That's the issue.
>
> #### 2) Fixing First Issue Give Birth To Another Issues
>
> I fixed the first issue by pushing audio chunk got from backend in an array and then creating a Blob object from that array of audio chunks and then create a url using `URL.createObjectURL(audioBlobCreatedFromArray);` and set it to state using `useState()`. This process will be repeated each time the next bytes are fetched. Finally, I got fix to first issue but updating state each time play audio from start because of each time a new url to blob is getting.
> Another issue is that when user try to interact with progress bar and get the playing head  to the middle or end. How can i manage the playback to at that point. It's a totally messy and ugly approach that i had implemented.
>
> #### What I Need?
>
> I Need Frontend Implementation similar to the Spotify (not exact but at least basic similar working exmpple). Like how Spotify doing to set proper bytes ranges into their proper place on the progress-bar and can be get from any point by moving the playing head at that timestamp. And strange thing is that there is no `audio` or `iframe` element in DOM.

#### Wanna See My Poor Frontend Implementation

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

const AudioPlayer = ({ audioBookId, sectionIndex }) => {
  const [audioChunks, setAudioChunks] = useState([]);
  const [audioBlob, setAudioBlob] = useState(null);
  const [audioURL, setAudioURL] = useState(null);
  const [played, setPlayed] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the initial audio data (500KB)
    fetchAudioData(0, 50000);
  }, []);

  const fetchAudioData = async (start, end) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:5000/api/audioBook/stream/${audioBookId}/${sectionIndex}`,
        { headers: { Range: `bytes=${start}-${end}` } }
      );

      if (response.ok) {
        setAudioURL()
        const blob = await response.blob();
        handleAudioChunk(blob);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching audio data:", error);
    }
  };

  const handleAudioChunk = async (chunkData) => {
    // Append the received audio chunk to the array
    setAudioChunks((prevChunks) => [...prevChunks, chunkData]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (audioChunks.length > 0) {
      // Create a Blob from all audio chunks
      const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: "audio/mpeg" });

      // Create an object URL from the Blob
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);

      // Set the audio Blob and URL
      setAudioBlob(audioBlob);
      setAudioURL(url);
    }
  }, [audioChunks]);

  const handleProgress = (state) => {
    // Update the played percentage
    setPlayed(state.played);
    console.log(state);
    // Check if we need to fetch more data when close to the end
    if (state.played > 0.9) {
      const nextStart = Math.floor(audioChunks.length * 50000 + 1);
      const nextEnd = nextStart + 50000 - 1;
      fetchAudioData(nextStart, nextEnd);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {audioURL ? (
        <ReactPlayer
          height="80px"
          url={audioURL}
          controls
          onProgress={handleProgress}
          config={{ file: { forceAudio: true } }}
        />
      ) : (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default AudioPlayer;
```

#### Wanna See My Backend Implementation?

```js
const getAudioFileStream = async (req, res) => {
  const { range } = req.headers;
  const { audioBookId, sectionIndex } = req.params;

  // Check the format of range is correct or not
  if (!/^bytes=\d+-\d+$/.test(range)) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: "FAILED",
      description: "Range: incorrect format or missing",
    });
  }

  try {
    // Get the start and end with parsed as integer
    let [start, end] = range
      .replace(/bytes=/, "")
      .split("-")
      .map((part) => {
        return parseInt(part, 10);
      });

    // A projection string that will make sure to get the specific listen url based on section index.
    const PROJECTION = {
      sections: { $arrayElemAt: ["$sections", Number(sectionIndex)] },
    };

    const audioBookSection = await AudioBookModel.getAudioBookById(
      audioBookId,
      PROJECTION
    );

    if (audioBookSection.status === "SUCCESS") {
      if (!audioBookSection.data.sections.length) {
        return res
          .status(404)
          .send({ message: "FAILED", description: "Section not found" });
      }
      const audioFileUrl = audioBookSection.data.sections[0].listen_url;

      const audioFileHead = await axios.head(audioFileUrl);
      const fileSize = parseInt(audioFileHead.headers["content-length"], 10);

      end = end < fileSize ? end : fileSize - 1;

      const chunkSize = end - start + 1;

      res.status(206).header({
        "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
        "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
        "Content-Length": chunkSize,
        "Content-Type": "audio/mpeg",
      });

      const audioFileStream = await axios.get(audioFileUrl, {
        responseType: "stream",
        headers: { Range: `bytes=${start}-${end}` },
      });

      audioFileStream.data.pipe(res);
    } else if (audioBookSection.status === "FAILED") {
      return res.status(404).send({
        message: audioBookSection.status,
        description: "Audio book not found",
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(500).send({
        message: audioBookSection.status,
        error: audioBookSection.error,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send({
      status: "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR",
      error: {
        message: error.message,
        identifier: "0x000B02", // for only development purpose while debugging
        stack: error.stack,
      },
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

> As I researched and came to know in progressive download there is a major drawback the file has to be downloaded from start to that point from where user want to listen even from the end.

Your research is wrong.

The browser is smart enough to download just what it needs.  For servers that support ranged requests, the browser will automatically make those range requests.  It will also intelligently pre-cache based on available client bandwidth, storage, and even battery when applicable.

It's important to note that plain old MP3 is not inherently seekable... so you should use a container format that is, which is pretty much anything except for bare MP3.

For an audiobook, you should really be using the Opus codec anyway, which is far more efficient for a given audio quality.  And then, you can use WebM for the container.

> After struggling with the frontend issues, I inspected Spotify web app; it is also getting content of a song in bytes ranges. I saw headers include Ranges, Content-Length etc just like me. But issue is how can I implement on client side

Yeah, the browser does this for you.  You don't need to implement anything.  Just plug the URL in as the audio `src` and you're good to go.  You will probably still want separate audio files for entire chapters, just to make it so that entire chapters can be cached for offline listening without caching the entire book.

> And strange thing is that there is no audio or iframe element in DOM.

You don't need one.  A simple `new Audio('https://example.com/woot.webm')` works fine.

Comment: Thanks. for this valuable answer... But the issue is that i cant send my source url of audio file to the client because I have to protect an audio content becaause it is a property of narrator (who read and records book)  and dont want to expose the source url

Comment: @m-naeem66622 But you are exposing the source URL... it doesn't matter if you do something hacky to chop it up into little pieces and send it to the client.  It's still trivial to extract.  If you want to protect your content, you should use DRM via Encrypted Media Extensions.  Just beware that this is particularly useless for audio content, and can be expensive and time consuming to implement, while reducing the platforms you can be compatible with.